# Infinite tamely ramified $p$-extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ contain infinite unramified subextensions?

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-theory

Let $p$ be a prime. By a $ p $-extension we mean a Galois extension whose Galois group is a $ p $-group. Let $L$ be an infinite tamely ramified $p$-extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e. all primes ramified in $ L/\mathbb{Q} $ are tamely ramified.

**Question:** Are there intermediate fields $L\supset K\supset F\supset \mathbb{Q} $ such that $F/\mathbb{Q}$ is finite and $K/F$ is an infinite everywhere unramified $ p $-extension?

Comment: Surely not. For one thing, if the extension is (pro-)abelian, then any $F$ can only have finite unramified subextensions by finiteness of the class group.

Comment: @JoachimKönig If the extension $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is abelian (or even solvable), then it is finite by CFT. But I assume that $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is infinite.

Comment: I don't understand, there are infinitely many tame $C_p$-extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$, and their compositum is tame and infinite. Is there some assumption missing?

Comment: @JoachimKönig  Oh, sorry. I should add the condition that the extension is unramified outside a finite set of primes.